# How to make Red Hat JBOSS Server read Spring Boot's application.properties file instead of standalone.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss

I want jboss to read properties from spring-boot.war file's inner `application.properties` file. When i deploy my application as `war`  i get these error

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.
DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: 
Error creating bean with name 'spring.mvc-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcProperties': Could not bind properties to 'WebMvcProperties' : prefix=spring.mvc, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; 
nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.mvc.servlet' to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcProperties$Servlet
```

What can i do to configure this?

Thanks

Comment: Why would JBoss read Spring Boot's configuration, or the other way around? What's the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: @Kayaman I edited question, Thanks. All Datasource and context path and port info is located in application.properties